# How to send/receive a JSON variable to PHP?

Tags: php, swift

I have the following swift code that has a dictionary and I'm trying to send it to PHP.

Since PHP doesn't have dictionaries, I thought I should convert the dictionary in swift to JSON and then send it as JSON to PHP.

However, I'm just not sure how to do that...

Also, how do I receive it in PHP side?

**swift code:**

```
func appl(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("...........................................................")
    
    let group = DispatchGroup() // just to avoid asnc
    let mappedViewsArray = DisplayVC.viewsArray.map { ($0,1) } // To count the similirities
    let viewsArrayCount = Dictionary(mappedViewsArray, uniquingKeysWith: +) // To add the similirities
    print(viewsArrayCount)
    do {
        let encodedDictionary = try JSONEncoder().encode(viewsArrayCount) // Convert the dictionary to JSON (encode)
        
        // let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: viewsArrayCount)
        
        
        
        let urlPath : String = "http://localhost/updateViews.php" // PHP file URL
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST" // method
        // request.httpBody = encodedDictionary
        print(viewsArrayCount)
        let postString = "JSONDataEncoded=\(encodedDictionary)" // to get the passed data in PHP
        // request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        //  request.httpBody = encodedDictionary
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) // to encode the passed variable
        group.enter() // just to avoid asnc
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in defer {group.leave()}
            // just to avoid asnc
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to update data")
            } else {
                print("Data updated")
               
                //let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
               // if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                 //   print(responseJSON)
             //   }
                
            }
        }
        task.resume() // to run the task command
        group.wait() // just to avoid asnc
        
        
        
        // to print the jsonencoded
    print(String(data: encodedDictionary, encoding: .utf8)!)
    } catch {
        print("fail")
        print("Error: ", error)
    }
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    // Create connection to database
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","");
     
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // $dictionary = [5:1,1:2,3:3,9:4,13:5];
    // $json = '{"5":1,"1":2,"3":3,"9":4,"13":5}';
    // $json = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['JSONDataEncoded']);
    $json = $_POST["JSONDataEncoded"];
    $updateViews = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($updateViews as $key => $value) {

        $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE cars SET views = views + '".$value."' WHERE ID = '". $key ."'");

        $stmt->execute();
        echo "good";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP has a stonking great SQL injection hole in it. Someone could post some JSON here that, at the very least, would run the `UPDATE` across all rows in `cars`. Depending on your MySQL settings they might even be able to drop the table too.

Comment: (Use parameter binding instead of `real_escape_string` - it is much safer).

Comment: As to the broader question, it looks like you have given an example (in a comment) for what is contained in `$_POST["JSONDataEncoded"]` when it gets to the PHP listener. You appear to have decoded it correctly, and the `foreach` loop looks good. Have you tried running it? What happens?

Comment: @halfer good catch regarding the sql injection possibility

Comment: you are not sending swift dictionary to php, and there's no relation whatsoever between swift dictionary and what PHP will receive, as they communicate via HTTP. You are sending at the moment JSON array to PHP, which is what it expects. So if you have issues, it's probably because of what you put in that array before JSON-encoding it - hard to say as we don't know what's inside that array. Side note: `let group = DispatchGroup() // just to avoid asnc` <-- is a really bad idea. Don't do that. Use async/await or a proper callback instead

Comment: @akjndklskver this is the data sample: `[5:1,1:2,3:3,9:4,13:5]`, assuming that the key represents a car and the value represents the views. for example, 5:1 means, vehicle 5 was viewed 1 time.

Comment: PHP does have dictionaries. They are called associative arrays.

Comment: @ryantxr how do i receive the dictionary on the PHP said as associative array?

Comment: Send the data as JSON. This would probably work: `{"5":1, "1":2, "3":3, "9":4, "13":5}`

Comment: @ryantxr ok so thats exactly what im trying to do instead of converting the dictionary to associative array. the issue is I am not sure how to send that JSON from the swift  code to PHP code. notice i have a sample already in PHP file `$json = '{"5":1,"1":2,"3":3,"9":4,"13":5}';` Im just stuck as to how do i send it from the swift and receive it in the PHP file, hence this post

Comment: Then you need help with the Swift part, not PHP

Comment: @ryantxr ive stumbled on this post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036238/8397835 and looks like this is how to send JSON encoded from swift but missing how to handle it from PHP side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been too long since I wrote Swift code. I am not going to attempt that. I will assume that you can convert your data into JSON.
Create JSON that looks like this:

```
{"5":1, "1":2, "3":3, "9":4, "13":5}
```

You can use HTTP/POST to send the data as shown in your code.
Using a POST variable should work. You could also just send JSON in the body and encode the POST request content-type as application/json. The only difference is that you have to read it differently.

```
// Read from post variable
$json = $_POST['JSONDataEncoded'];
```

Read directly from body

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Once you have the JSON, converting it is the same

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($data as $key => $row ) {
    echo "$key, $row"; // just an example
}
```

Comment: Good point about reading the JSON directly from the body. However, if the OP sends it in a variable, then the PHP they have may already be right. I am not entirely convinced they are sending it correctly, and I wonder if that would be the next thing to check.

Comment: would you know how I can test what Im receiving in PHP file? I know if I write a PHP file, I can place it in a server like Apache and do an echo to test it out locally. However, Im not sure if Im passing the JSON from swift to PHP how I can echo to test it out/debug

Comment: @Cataster: See the `$json = file_get_contents('php://input')` line - that will show what raw data is being sent.

Comment: Personally I would check it in the Swift though - and add some unit tests around it.

Comment: @halfer So I just have to do echo $json then in PHP and it should display? The reason I wanna test it in PHP side not swift is because i want to check if I'm actually receiving the json encoded data. Right now idk if I'm receiving it. Also, is input in php://input supposed to be the file name? Or is that the format of receiving from PHP? I know you mentioned it's been a while since writing swift but would you guide me in how do I send the JSON in the body and encode the POST request content-type as application/json?

Comment: No, `'php://input'` is not a placeholder for a filename - use that explicitly. It is a PHP-specific protocol to grab the whole of the HTTP request body. Try it, and this will give you very clear directions as to how to proceed. If the JSON is valid then the Swift code is OK, and if it is invalid, the Swift is not OK. Make sure you try adjusting the Swift code so it sends JSON in the whole POST body (i.e. not as a value of `JSONDataEncoded`) first.

Comment: Once you have tried that, you can then also (instead) try sending the JSON in that POST var. Make sure you make parallel adjustments in the PHP, as ryantxr has indicated.

Comment: @halfer this `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` worked! Really appreciate the help guys. The other method did not work because it is being encoded twice. When I decode it once, I get empty array.